# How to swap multiple images from multiple galleries using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I realized that I didn't format my previous question well, so I deleted it and changed the format a bit. Hopefully, this will be more helpful to you guys.
I am trying to create a site that will allow users to create their own t-shirts. The T-shirts have a logo on them and I am allowing users to change the colors of the left and right eye independently, the outlines for the left and right eye. The color of the mouth and its outline as well as the entire logo's color. Here is an example of the code:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="accordion"> Logo Colors </button>
    <div class="panel" id="logogallery">
        <img id="SuperPrimrose" src="Markers/LogoMarkers/SuperPrimrose.jpg" alt="SuperPrimrose">
        <img id="SuperLemonYellow" src="Markers/LogoMarkers/SuperLemonYellow.jpg" alt="SuperLemonYellow">
        <img id="Gold8000" src="Markers/LogoMarkers/Gold8000.jpg" alt="Gold8000">
    </div

<button class="accordion"> Left Eye Colors </button>
    <div class="panel" id="LEgallery">
        <img id="LEBearsNavy" src="Markers/LEMarkers/BearsNavy.jpg" alt="BearsNavy" title="BearsNavy">
        <img id="LEBlack" src="Markers/LEMarkers/Black.jpg" alt="Black">
        <img id="LEBlackLightGreen" src="Markers/LEMarkers/BlackLightGreen.jpg" alt="BlackLightGreen" title="Black">
       </div>

<button class="accordion"> Right Eye Colors </button>
    <div class="panel" id="REgallery">
        <img id="REBearsNavy" src="Markers/LogoMarkers/BearsNavy.jpg" alt="BearsNavy" title="BearsNavy">
        <img id="REBlack" src="Markers/LogoMarkers/Black.jpg" alt="Black">
       </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#logogallery {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
}

div#logogallery img {
    width: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
}
div#logofullsize {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
    top: 350px;
    right: 750px;
    background-size: contain;

div#LEgallery {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
}

div#LEgallery img {
    width: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
}
div#LEfullsize {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
    top: 350px;
    right: 750px;
    background-size: contain;
}


/*Logo Color Image Style CSS*/

div.SuperPrimrose {
    background: url('Colors/LogoColor/SuperPrimrose.png') no-repeat left top;
}

div.SuperLemonYellow {
    background: url('Colors/LogoColor/SuperLemonYellow.png') no-repeat left top;
}

div.Gold8000 {
    background: url('Colors/LogoColor/Gold8000.png') no-repeat left top;


/*LE Color Image Style CSS*/

div.LESuperPrimrose {
    background: url('Colors/LEColor/SuperPrimrose.png') no-repeat left top;
    }
div.LESuperLemonYellow {
    background: url('Colors/LEColor/SuperLemonYellow.png') no-repeat left top;
    }
div.LEGold8000 {
    background: url('Colors/LEColor/Gold8000.png') no-repeat left top;
    }
div.LESuperDolphinYellow {
    background: url('Colors/LEColor/SuperDolphinYellow.png') no-repeat left top;
```

**JQUERY:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(e) {
            var newclass = $(this).attr("id");
            var oldclass = $("#logofullsize").attr('class');
            $("#logofullsize").fadeOut(function() {
                $("#logofullsize").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
            })
        })
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(e) {
            var newclass = $(this).attr("id");
            var oldclass = $("#LEfullsize").attr('class');
            $("#LEfullsize").fadeOut(function() {
                $("#LEfullsize").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
            })
        })
    });
```

The site is set up so that you click a drop down (ex Logo Colors, LE Colors etc) and thumbnail colors appear. you click the color and the logo on the page changes to that specific color. I have 2 problems.

1. I can't get all elements to appear on the page at once, meaning, only the main logo appears on the page. But the eyes, mouth, and outlines for them all don't show.
2. Let's say the main logo appears on the page. I can click the "logo" drop down and the colors will appear. I click a color and the logo changes to the specified color. However, let's say I click the "left eye" drop down and click a color from there. Instead of changing the color of the eye in the logo, it swaps out the logo for a picture of the left eye in that color.

How can I make it so all of the elements of the logo "eyes, mouth, outlines, etc appear on the page together and make it so when I click a marker from either left eye, right eye, mouth, etc. it doesn't change the overall image, just that aspect?

Comment: Could you set up a demo? jsfiddle or codepen etc

Comment: Here is the link to the codepen https://codepen.io/R1CKRUD3/pen/OmeqLe